# laravel - boilerplate routes

Tags: php, laravel, boilerplate

I have the route:

```
Route::get('donepayment', ['as' => 'paymentsuccess', 'uses' => 'PaymentsController@paymentsuccess']);
```

It works fine it is not under a namespace, but when under a namespace like this,

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
 Route::group(['namespace' => 'User', 'as' => 'user.'], function () {

      Route::get('donepayment', ['as' => 'paymentsuccess', 'uses' => 'PaymentsController@paymentsuccess']);
```

it doesn't work. Can someone help me solve this issue.

Comment: Route::namespace('User')->group(function () {
    // Make sure your PaymentsController resides in "App\Http\Controllers\Admin" Namespace
});

Comment: It doesn't work will not help us to solve the problem, tell us what you are trying to do, which error is showing or what is happening at least.

Comment: My controller in under frontend\user namespace, I need to call it when I am logged in as a user

Comment: like this "App\Http\Controllers\frontend\user"?

Comment: the link is coming from a controller in vendor, but the route controller is in frontend\user

Comment: thanks a lot. My problem is solved now. I had to specify my controller in the global routes like: Route::get('donepayment',['uses'=>'Frontend\User\PaymentsController@paymentsuccess', 'as'=>'paymentsuccess']);